# Algebras with a simple preserving duality and finite global dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Algebras with a simple preserving duality (an anti-automorphism preserving pointwise a primitive full set of ortohogonal idempotents) and finite global dimension include important classes of algebras such as Schur algebras and blocks of category $\mathcal{O}$, which are also quasi-hereditary.

> Question: Is there a (natural) example of an algebra with a simple preserving duality and finite global dimension that is not quasi-hereditary?